# How to write byte(s) to a file in C++?

Tags: c++, byte, bit, file-handling, huffman-code

I have created a bitset using `std::bitset<8> bits` which is equivalent to `00000000` i.e., 1 byte.
I have output file defined as `std::ofstream outfile("./compressed", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary)` but when I write the `bits` using `outfile << bits`, the content of `outfile` becomes `00000000` **but the size of file is 8 bytes. (each bit of `bits` end up taking 1 byte in the file)**. Is there any way to truly write byte to a file? For example if I write `11010001` then this should be written as a byte and the file size should be 1 byte not 8 bytes. I am writing a code for Huffman encoder and I am not able to find a way to write the encoded bytes to the output compressed file.

Comment: The output operator `<<` is *textual*, it will write as text. You need to [write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) the raw data instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `operator<<` is the text encoding method, even if you've specified `std::ofstream::binary`. You can use [`put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) to write a single binary character or [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) to output multiple characters. Note that you are responsible for the conversion of data to its `char` representation.

```
std::bitset<8> bits = foo();
std::ofstream outfile("compressed", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);

// In reality, your conversion code is probably more complicated than this
char repr = bits.to_ulong();

// Use scoped sentries to output with put/write
{
    std::ofstream::sentry sentry(outfile);
    if (sentry)
    {
        outfile.put(repr);                  // <- Option 1
        outfile.write(&repr, sizeof repr);  // <- Option 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have just one more question and then I will accept your answer. In the line `char repr = bits.to_ulong();` you have written the comment `your conversion code is probably more complicated than this`. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Casting the `unsigned long` returned from `to_ulong` into a `char` will only work when the bitset uses 8 or fewer bits. If you use more than that, things will get more complicated.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks!